# VcXsrv host-based access control not working

Tags: windows, xserver

All VcXsrv examples on internet is to run it with disabled access control, with '-ac' switch. But I'd actually like to turn on the host-based access control, so far not working.

First I launch VcXsrv from my windows 10 PC (latest build/patch) named pc1, with the -auth switch.

```
> "C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -auth "C:\users\myname\hosts.txt"
```

In hosts.txt, I have the following, where linux1 is the remote host name

```
localhost
inet6:localhost
linux1
inet6:linux1
192.168.1.191
inet6:192.168.1.191
```

The ip addresses are linux1's.

However, when I launch xterm from linux1, I got this error

```
linux1$ /usr/bin/xterm -display pc1:0
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
/usr/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: pc1:0
```

From pc1 loacally, when I run xhost, there is no mentioning of my remote host or its ip.

```
C:\Program Files\VcXsrv>xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
INET:pc1.mshome.net
LOCAL:
INET:pc1
INET6:pc1
```

Therefore, looks like '-auth' didn't load the hosts.txt file

Can anyone share some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So `-auth` is for a different authentication/access control mechanism. To use **host-based** access control, run commands similar to the following, on your Windows 10 PC:

```
xhost +inet:localhost
xhost +inet6:localhost
xhost +inet:linux1
xhost +inet6:linux1
xhost +inet:192.168.1.191
```

(But no need to explicitly repeat the last line with `inet6:`, since that is specifically an IPv4 address.)

Then run `xhost` by itself again. The new hostname(s) and IP address(es) should now appear. And connecting from any of them to VcXsrv should now work.

Comment: Stephen, sorry for my late reply and thank you for paying attention to this old question. I checked my old notes. Manually running xhost under C:\Program Files\VcXsrv worked but my goal was to avoid doing this every time after I restarted computer. The inet6 comment is helpful. I gave you thumbs-up for this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your vcxsrv installation dir, like C:\Program Files\VcXsrv.
Find a file named "X0.hosts"
Open it with notepad.exe.
Add the things you want!

Comment: Changming, thank you for checking this thread. Under that folder, there is a X0 file, no X0.hosts file. The X0 file has two entries, only for localhost, but remote hosts can still connect to XcXsrv. According to manual, the only way to control remote host access is to use '-auth file', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try with root user, to become root user  : sudo -i